# Jquery if browser

Tags: jquery

I am using a tooltip I got a positioning error on ie. I put a jquery browser code

**MY Tooltip**

```
$('.tooltip').tooltip({
    position: "bottom center"
  });
```

Then I want to add an argument like this

```
 $.browser.msie({
    // I wanted to add tooltip setting here
  });
```

How can I do that? please help

Answer (score 3):

Not the best idea to detect the browser instead of the capabilities but I'm not one to frown and not give an answer. Use the jQuery Browser plugin:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give special instructions for every version of IE, use the following:

```
if($.browser.msie){
  //ie tooltip code
} else {
  //default tooltip code
}
```

You can narrow it down further by version number.  As others have suggested, look at the [jQuery API documentation for $.browser()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).

**Update:**

This API ($.browser) was removed in jQuery 1.9.  The recommended approach to building web applications is to use feature detection to determine what features a browser supports.  Libraries such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) help with this.

Comment: It is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")>=0)

{
// your code for opera
}

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>=0)
{ 
// for IE
} 
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mozilla")>=0)
{
    //for firefox
}
```

or

```
if (document.all) { 
        //for IE
       } else { 
        // or other 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match("/MSIE/")) {
    // code for IE here
} else {
    // code for everyone else
}
```

I don't normally use regex, so it could be wrong. Any regex pattern will work for the `match()` method.

Comment: Like I said, check the regex.